# Counting intersections between line and points using Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, line, intersection

I'm using QGIS 3.12 and let's say I have a Layer that consists in Lines that represent 'Rivers', and I have another Layer that consists in Points that represent 'Bridges'.

Can I count the number of intersections between these two Layers using Field Calculator?

[image]

In the example given the objective would be to have the attribute 'Inters_Bri' be equal to 5 using the Field Calculator because I have 5 bridges intersecting the Blue River.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your question to ask your most pressing question.

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried by so far and where you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use an expression like this:

```
aggregate('pointlayername','count','a',intersects($geometry,aggregate('linelayername','collect',$geometry)))
```

Note that this will only work if they perfectly overlap (intersect), not if they are 1 millimeters or even less apart. In that case, you could use a suitable buffer.